# strtok() with char **argv in C

Tags: c, strtok

I have this project in which I need to use the arguments passed when someone calls this program. The condition is that the token delimiter is ' " ' and I can't do it.

I've tried with strcpy but all the ' " ' simply disappear. Now I'm trying with memcpy but I'm getting this weird characters when I print the tokens.(note that I don't need to print them, I just want to know if I have the right thing in my hands so that I can "do things" to that information.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  const char symb = (char)2;
  char *comm;
  char* offset = comm;
  int i;
  //put all args together
  for(i = 1; i< argc; i++){
    memcpy(offset, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    offset+=strlen(argv[i]);
  }    
  char *token;
  token = strtok(comm, &symb);
  while(token != NULL){
    printf("\n%s\n", token);//debugging
    //do stuff with args
    token = strtok(NULL, &symb);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

I understand that argv has all the string separated by " ", but I think it should keep ' " ' too. I'm sorry if this is too confuse, but I tried to be specific. I'll resume it:

when someone writes:

```
$./prog op "tup1" "tup2 is the best" "tup3"
```

I want to do op with "tup1" "tup2 is the best" and "tup3"
so I need to get it all together after argv separates it and then get the tokens with '"' delimiter. But when I debug with printf I get this:

```
$n�Y
$n@
$n �k
$n�Y
$n�Y
$n�Y
$nY
$n l
$Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what shell are you using? bash, windows command line?

Comment: You didn't allocate memory to `char *comm;`

Comment: The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function takes a proper string as second argument, just not a number. Pass e.g. `"2"` if you want to tokenize on the character `'2'`. Not passing a string causes the program to have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: i'm using GNU bash @thumbmunkeys

Comment: Look for quoting. Your programme doesn't see the quotes, they're interpreted (and removed) by your shell.

Comment: Your shell is eating the quotation marks. Try `$./prog op \"tup1\" \"tup2 is the best\" \"tup3\"` instead. You have to escape the quotation marks in BASH because it uses them to tokenize groups of items with spaces into a single argument.

Comment: Also note that `strtok` *modifies* the string passed as the first argument, and so can't be used on constant or read-only strings, and you should always consider the strings passed in `argv` as read-only.

Comment: ahhh so BASH itself removes quotes.. ok thanks to you all. I'll try another solution. Now i understand where is the problem.

Comment: @gNp93 Yes, bash is removing the quotes, *but* you still have an issue in that you're copying strings into garbage memory. You have to allocate your `comm` pointer as P0W suggested.

Comment: yes i did it already, problem solved!! :D @JasonCoco